# how to specify ports number for both sides of a tcp connection (client and server side) in c using sockets

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, port, client-server

I am trying to replicate this diagram in C:

[image]

I have created the request line connection fine, but I can't find any information that has worked on how to create a connection where both sides have specified port numbers as seen in the reply line in the diagram. So far, I have only been able to specify one side of a connection.

Server code:

```c
#include "acc.h"

int main() {
    int listenSocket, connSocket, clientDataPort, dataSocket, conStat;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr, clientAddr, dataAddr;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    socklen_t clientLen;
    ssize_t bytesRead;

    listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_TCP_PORT);

    bind(listenSocket, (SA*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));

    listen(listenSocket, MAX_CLIENTS);

    printf("Server listening on port %d (Port L)...\n", SERV_TCP_PORT);

    clientLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    connSocket = accept(listenSocket, (SA*)&clientAddr, &clientLen);

    printf("Client connected for control: %s : %d (Ephemeral Port)\n", inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port));

    bytesRead = recv(connSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';

    clientDataPort = atoi(buffer);
    printf("Received client's data port: %d (Port U)\n", clientDataPort);

    close(connSocket);
    printf("request line closed\n");


    dataSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&dataAddr, 0, sizeof(dataAddr));
    dataAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dataAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    dataAddr.sin_port = htons(clientDataPort);

    if ((conStat = connect(dataSocket, (SA*)&dataAddr, sizeof(dataAddr))) < 0) {
        printf("connect failed\n");  // error connecting to remote socket
    } else {
        printf("Connected to client's data port: %d\n", clientDataPort);
    }

    close(dataSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```c
#include "acc.h"

int main() {
    int cliSocket, dataSocket, dataConnSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr, dataAddr;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    socklen_t dataLen;
    
    cliSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_TCP_PORT);

    connect(cliSocket, (SA*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    
    printf("Connected to server for control on port: %d\n", SERV_TCP_PORT);

    sprintf(buffer, "%d", CLI_TCP_PORT);
    send(cliSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);

    close(cliSocket);
    printf("request line closed\n");

    dataSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&dataAddr, sizeof(dataAddr));
    dataAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dataAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    dataAddr.sin_port = htons(CLI_TCP_PORT);

    bind(dataSocket, (SA*)&dataAddr, sizeof(dataAddr));

    listen(dataSocket, MAX_CLIENTS);

    printf("Client listening for data on port: %d...\n", CLI_TCP_PORT);

    dataLen = sizeof(dataAddr);
    if((dataConnSocket = accept(dataSocket, (SA*)&dataAddr, &dataLen)) < 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "accept failed\n");
    exit (1);
    }
    
    printf("Server connected on data port: %d\n", CLI_TCP_PORT);
    printf("%s : %d\n", inet_ntoa(dataAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(dataAddr.sin_port));

    close(dataConnSocket);
    close(dataSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

acc.h file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define MAXLINE 4096
#define LISTENQ 1024
#define SERV_TCP_PORT   50090 // port L
#define CLI_TCP_PORT    50094 // port U
#define SA struct sockaddr
#define MAX_CLIENTS 10
```

How I need the programs to be setup:

> For request-line, the server listens (passive mode) on a port L. A client initiates request-line (active mode) to the server on port L. On the other hand, for reply-line, the server uses port L+1 in active mode, and the client is in a passive mode on port U. The client sends to the server its port number U via request-line so that the server can initiate reply-line to the port. The reply-line is closed by the server when the request-line is closed.

If what I have described here is different to what I have stated I'm trying to do before, please let me know what I have misunderstood. Everywhere I have looked says its either not possible or I need to use `bind()` twice on both sides of a connection, which hasn't work.

If solved, any code (ie `printf()`'s) to prove that all ports are specified and connected correctly would be much appreciated.

Edit:
i made some changes to the server code:

```c
#include "acc.h"

int main() {
    int listenSocket, connSocket, clientDataPort, dataSocket, conStat;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr, servAddr1, clientAddr, dataAddr;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    socklen_t clientLen;
    ssize_t bytesRead;

    listenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_TCP_PORT);

    bind(listenSocket, (SA*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));

    listen(listenSocket, MAX_CLIENTS);

    printf("Server listening on port %d (Port L)...\n", SERV_TCP_PORT);

    clientLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    connSocket = accept(listenSocket, (SA*)&clientAddr, &clientLen);

    printf("Client connected for control: %s : %d (Ephemeral Port)\n", inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port));

    bytesRead = recv(connSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';

    clientDataPort = atoi(buffer);
    printf("Received client's data port: %d (Port U)\n", clientDataPort);

    close(connSocket);
    printf("request line closed\n");

    dataSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&dataAddr, sizeof(dataAddr));
    dataAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dataAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    dataAddr.sin_port = htons(clientDataPort);

    // VVVVVVVV CHANGES HERE VVVVVVVVV
    bzero(&servAddr1, sizeof(servAddr1));
    servAddr1.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr1.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servAddr1.sin_port = htons(SERV_TCP_PORT+1);
    bind(dataSocket, (SA*)&servAddr1, sizeof(servAddr1));

    if ((conStat = connect(dataSocket, (SA*)&dataAddr, sizeof(dataAddr))) < 0) {
        printf("connect failed\n");  // error connecting to remote socket
    } else {
        printf("Connected to client's data port: %d\n", clientDataPort);
    }

    close(dataSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

this seems to work but i just wanted to check if this is the best way to do it, thanks for the feedback, much appreciated.

Comment: The client should create the data socket before sending the port number to the server. Otherwise, the server might try to connect to the port before the client has started listening.

Comment: You wrote that `bind` did not work. Please [edit] your question and show how exactly you used it and how exactly it failed. (If you get `EADDRINUSE` you might have to use `SO_REUSEADDR` or `SO_REUSEPORT`.) You should check the return value of all functions.

Comment: Why do you want two connections? The first one is full-duplex. You don't need two.

Comment: And why do you want fixed client ports at both ends? None of this is necessary.

Comment: @user207421 most protocols would agree with you. But there are valid cases for this. The FTP protocol works this way during Active-mode data transfers, for example. And some peer-to-peer chat/data sharing services, too

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the diagram is fairly straight forward:

1. the **server** creates a socket, `bind()`'s it to port `L` and calls `listen()` on it, then calls `accept()` to receive an inbound connection, and then calls `recv()` to receive data from that socket connection.
2. the **client** creates a socket, optionally <sup>1</sup> `bind()`'s it to port `0` instructing the OS to pick a random ephemeral port, then `connect()`'s it to port `L` on the server.

   <sup>1</sup> If you omit this `bind()`, `connect()` will choose the ephemeral port.
3. the **client** creates a 2nd socket, `bind()`'s it to port `U` (which can be either a specific port or another ephemeral port, you decide), calls `listen()` on it, and then `send()`'s port `U` to the server over the 1st socket connection and `accept()`'s a connection on the 2nd socket.
4. the **server** `recv()`'s Port `U` from the 1st socket connection, then creates a 2nd socket, `bind()`'s it to port `L+1`, `connect()`'s it to port `U` on the client, and then `send()`'s its reply over this 2nd socket connection.

As far as that diagram is concerned, that is all that is needed.

---

As far as your code is concerned:

- there is a complete lack of adequate error handling on both sides. But let's overlook that for the moment.
- you really should be sending the client port as a binary `uint16_t` integer instead of as a null-terminated string. But let's overlook that for the moment, too.
- your client is handling the 1st connection correctly (except it should not be `close()`'ing this connection after `send()`'ing the request, as that violates the rules given to you).

  - However, your client is sending its request to the server *BEFORE* it has even *created* its 2nd `listen`'ing socket.  So the server may try to `connect()` to port `U` before it has been opened.

    **The client needs to actually be `listen()`'ing on port `U` *before* it can then tell the server to `connect()` to port `U`.**
- your server is handling the 1st connection correctly (except it should not be `close()`'ing this connection yet once it `recv()`'s the client's data, as this violates the rules given to you).

  - However, your server is not `bind()`'ing the 2nd socket at all, let alone to port `L+1`, before `connect()`'ing it to the client.

    **While omitting this will likely not affect the server's ability to connect to the client, it does violate the rules given to you.**

Comment: thanks for the help, im still unsure on how i can successfully connect the cli & srv using bind on both sockets with different port #s. In the 1st connection SERV_TCP_PORT is used as the port # on both sides of the connection, where as on the 2nd connection i need different port #s. I understand that i need to bind both sides of the connection with different port #s but im still unsure of what that looks like (ie; what changes need to be made for a bind on both side of the connection to work), i dont know the correct syntax/call order for binding on both sides of a connection.

Comment: I literally told you exactly what you needed to do, step by step, on both sides. What exactly are you still unclear about?